# Sparkstreaming hangs after creating kafka consumer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to get a very simple kafka + sparkstreaming integration.

On the kafka side, I cloned this repository (https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images) and did a docker-compose up to get an instance of zookeeper and kafka running. I created a topic called "foo" and added messages. In this case, kafka is running on port 29092.

On the spark side, my build.sbt file looks like this:

```
name := "KafkaSpark"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion
)
```

I was able to get the following code snippet running from consuming data from the terminal:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._

object SparkTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(3))

    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)

    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
    val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)

    // Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
    wordCounts.print()
    ssc.start()             // Start the computation
    ssc.awaitTermination()  // Wait for the computation to terminate


  }
}
```

So the sparkstreaming is working.

Now, I created the following to consume from kafka:

```
 import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
 import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.count
 import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
 import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
 import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
 import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
 import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructType, TimestampType}

object KafkaTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("Spark Word Count")
      .getOrCreate()

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(3))


    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:29092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "stream_group_id",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )

    val topics = Array("foo")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )



    stream.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
      val data = rdd.map(record => record.value)
      data.foreach(println)
      println(time)

    }

    ssc.start()             // Start the computation
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

When it runs, I get the following in the console (I'm running this in intellij). The process just hangs at the last line after "subscribing" to the topic. I've tried creating a topic that does not exist and I get the same result, i.e. it doesn't seem to throw an error despite the lack of a topic existing. If I create a non-existing broker, I do get an error (Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer) so it must be finding the broker when I do use the proper port.

Any suggestions on how to correct this issue?

Here's the log file:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/11/23 05:29:42 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0
17/11/23 05:29:42 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Spark Word Count
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jonathandick
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: jonathandick
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(jonathandick); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(jonathandick); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 59606.
17/11/23 05:29:48 DEBUG SparkEnv: Using serializer: class org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/w2/njgz3jnd097cdybxcvp9c2hw0000gn/T/blockmgr-3a3feb00-0fdb-4bc5-867d-808ac65d7c8f
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2004.6 MB
17/11/23 05:29:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/11/23 05:29:49 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
17/11/23 05:29:49 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
17/11/23 05:29:49 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4042. Attempting port 4043.
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4043.
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.1.67:4043
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 59613.
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.1.67:59613
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.67, 59613, None)
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.67:59613 with 2004.6 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.67, 59613, None)
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.67, 59613, None)
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.67, 59613, None)
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/Users/jonathandick/IdeaProjects/KafkaSpark/spark-warehouse/').
17/11/23 05:29:49 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/Users/jonathandick/IdeaProjects/KafkaSpark/spark-warehouse/'.
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
17/11/23 05:29:50 WARN StreamingContext: spark.master should be set as local[n], n > 1 in local mode if you have receivers to get data, otherwise Spark jobs will not get resources to process the received data.
17/11/23 05:29:50 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding enable.auto.commit to false for executor
17/11/23 05:29:50 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding auto.offset.reset to none for executor
17/11/23 05:29:50 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding executor group.id to spark-executor-stream_group_id
17/11/23 05:29:50 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding receive.buffer.bytes to 65536 see KAFKA-3135
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Slide time = 3000 ms
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Storage level = Serialized 1x Replicated
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Remember interval = 3000 ms
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream@1a38eb73
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO ForEachDStream: Slide time = 3000 ms
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO ForEachDStream: Storage level = Serialized 1x Replicated
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO ForEachDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO ForEachDStream: Remember interval = 3000 ms
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO ForEachDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@1e801ce2
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:29092]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    enable.auto.commit = false
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    interceptor.classes = null
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = 
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    max.poll.records = 2147483647
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    group.id = stream_group_id
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    auto.offset.reset = latest

17/11/23 05:29:50 DEBUG KafkaConsumer: Starting the Kafka consumer
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:29092]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    enable.auto.commit = false
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    interceptor.classes = null
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = consumer-1
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    max.poll.records = 2147483647
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    group.id = stream_group_id
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    auto.offset.reset = latest

17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.0.1
17/11/23 05:29:50 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : a7a17cdec9eaa6c5
17/11/23 05:29:50 DEBUG KafkaConsumer: Kafka consumer created
17/11/23 05:29:50 DEBUG KafkaConsumer: Subscribed to topic(s): foo
```

Comment: Have you added new messages to kafka after the spark process starts?  Maybe change `"auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",` to `"auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",` to see if it reads the messages published before it started?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I had tried both setting to earliest as well as adding more messages - neither had any effect. In the test spark run above, every 3 seconds, the console updates with a timestamp and several log messages. This does NOT happen with the kafka consumer. It makes me thing something is holding up the processing as no RDD's are being produced by spark.

Comment: I just ran your code as-is and it worked.  I wonder if the issue isn't really in your kafka setup and how you are writing your test data to the topic.  Does your kafka instance behave with the console producer and consumer in the kafka bin dirs?

Comment: Thanks navicore. Could you share with me the steps you took to create your kafka instance? For my Kafka setup, I'm using the steps found here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html. I cloned the repository and am running the kafka-single-node instance using docker-compose up.

Comment: I couldn't tell from the video how or at what point you started writing to kafka.  I suspect your spark process is waiting for messages to be written to the topic.  I run my dev instances via https://gist.github.com/navicore/017c6ab1d735596cecc2732e2faaa0dd.

Comment: Got it working with your kafka docker container. Thank you!!